# Java - Casting, Generics, Objects and Arrays

Tags: java, oop, generics

I was wondering if it is possible to convert an `Object` into something else.

I have a Object which contains a series of numbers in a random order such as: 3, 4, 2, 5, 1 and wondering if I am able to turn it into an int[] or select certain elements from it, as in a number from the sequence?

EDIT:
so some of the code i have is:

```
//This contains all the different combinations of the numbers
ArrayList routePop4 = new ArrayList();
//This picks out the first one, just as a test
Object test = routePop4.get(0);
```

But the idea is that I want to loop through each element of test.

Comment: **How** does it contain those numbers ? Give us some code.

Comment: One practical example can help you a lot, please.

Comment: What sort of object is `test`?  If you know what sort of object it is, you can cast it, for instance `ArrayList list = (ArrayList)test;`  But you would do better to use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) and have `routePop4` have a specified type.

Comment: Your example would be much more helpful if you mention what type of object you might expect to put in your `ArrayList`.

Comment: You're not asking about *casting*, you're asking about converting.  Java casts do not convert objects from one type to another, they merely verify that the reference variable being cast contains the type of object being cast to.  (Casts of *scalar* values is a slightly different issue, but the two types of casts are totally different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) cannot "contain a series of numbers".  However many subclasses of Object, such as all of the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) can "contain a series of numbers", and they come with a [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) method to turn the contents of the collection into an array.

If you have a collection, but only have access to it as an Object, you need to cast it before you can work with it properly:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = (ArrayList<Integer>)test;
Integer[] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[]{});
```

It's fairly rare in day-to-day Java to actually be working with variables cast as Object, if you are, it should be a red flag that you may be doing something wrong.  You can use [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) to allow objects that contain other objects to do so generically, like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1); // Can only add integers, list.add("a string") would fail at compile time
int n = list.get(0); // no need to cast, we know list only contains Integers
```

If you aren't using a Collection, you'll presumably need to roll your own, as Luke Taylor's answer suggests.  That said, you'll get better answers if you can provide more information, the current text of your question doesn't make sense in a Java context.

Comment: instanceof on `Collection` with any parameter doesn't work, this will not compile. The only way to check is to check every element manually or use Guava to filter the collection.

Comment: Thanks :) +1 (removal of downvote) and +1 again for the information there at the end. Raw typing (generic objects without a generic argument) isn't a good idea anyway because of all the type safety traps that can snare you.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your edit, I recommend taking advantage of generics.

When you declare an `ArrayList` you can indicate what kind of objects it's going to contain.

For example, if you know your ArrayList will contain Strings, you would do this:

`List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();`

If each element of your list is an array of Integers, you would do this:

`List<Integer[]> listOfIntegerArrays = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();`

Then you could get any element from your list and assign it to an Integer array like this:

`Integer[] integerArray = listOfIntegerArrays.get(0);`

Then you could iterate over every Integer in the list like this:

```
for (Integer loopInteger : integerArray) {
    System.out.println("The value: " + loopInteger);
}
```

Some more reading on generics:

- http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/java-generics-tutorial-part-i-basics.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int[] numbersFromObject = new int[yourObject.getAmountOfNumbers()];

// Initialize array with numbers from array
for(int i = 0; i < yourObject.getAmountOfNumbers(); i++) {
numbersFromObject[i] = yourObject.getNumber(i);

}
```

I'm not sure what methods your object contains, yet I'm sure you'll be able to adjust to the following mentioned above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You may as well put that logic inside the object itself.  You could create MyObject.toArray() and have _IT_ create and instantiate the array. That's kind of the point to object oriented programming.

Comment: it keeps coming up with "The method getAmountOfNumbers() is undefined for the type Object". I am using android, does this make a difference?

Comment: @ jahroy, this seems like a good idea. @ Andrew Murphy, no, this does not have anything to do with Android, it's because you have not created that method in the class you are creating the object from.